# Front End jQuery code not executing correctly with Node.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, node.js, express

I have an  automatic image scroller div that is comprised of a ul made of small images. The goal is to have a simple scroller that begins as soon as the page is loaded. It works perfectly when I simply run the code(Html, CSS and a js file with jquery) in the browser locally, but will not execute as expected when the app is running a node server.

I've tried to ensure my jQuery is being recognized and included a wrapping $(window).on("load") function around the main code that operates the scroller. Many of the similar posts ive looked into have this being the issue. I also double checked to see if the server is loading the external file, which it is. Console logs inside the function are showing up in the chrome console with no errors being thrown. Also looking into the chrome console shows the necessary images and external script being loaded into the page. Testing more of logging values inside the external function shows that the resources are being accessed, so perhaps this is a synchronicity issue with jQuery + node? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The jQuery

```
$(window).on("load", function () {

   $(function () {
       var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
       var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
       scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
       var curX = 0;
       scrollerContent.children().each(function () {
           var $this = $(this);
           $this.css('left', curX);
           curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
       });
       var fullW = curX / 2;
       var viewportW = scroller.width();

       var controller = { curSpeed: 0, fullSpeed: 1 };
       var $controller = $(controller);
       var tweenToNewSpeed = function (newSpeed, duration) {
           if (duration === undefined) {
               duration = 600;
               $controller.stop().animate({ curSpeed: newSpeed }, duration);
           }

       };
       var doScroll = function () {
           var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
           var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
           if (newX > fullW * 2 - viewportW)
               newX -= fullW;
           scroller.scrollLeft(newX);

       };
       setInterval(doScroll, 20);
       tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
       console.log("foo")
       console.log(scrollerContent);

   });
});
```

The server file

```
var express = require("express");
var db = require("./models/company.js");


var app = express();

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/public"));


require("./routes/htmlRoutes.js")(app);
require("./routes/apiRoutes.js")(app);

db.sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(function() {
  app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("App listening on PORT: " + PORT);
  });
})
module.exports = app;
```

Relevant CSS

```
#scroller {
    position: relative;
}
#scroller .innerScrollArea {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#scroller ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#scroller li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

relevant code from index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/index.css">


    <title>RepoMan</title>
</head>
...
    <!--AD Space-->
    <div id="scroller" style="width: 1110px; height: 75px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="innerScrollArea">
            <ul>
                <!-- Define photos here -->
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-allied.gif" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-baja.gif" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-bigtime.png" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-det.png" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-dyn.gif" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-ken.png" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-locating.png" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-minuteman.png" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-nams.jpeg" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-rec.png" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-recmng.gif" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-repfl.png" /></li>
                <li><img class="ad-img" src="assets/images/sidebar/sm-rsig.gif" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
...


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "UW2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your index.html, package.json, some info about your build process? I will need more information

Comment: You dont need the `$(window).on("load", function () {});` use your anonymous function or use `$(document).ready(function(){ });` and place your jQuery code inside it.

Comment: ive added the package.json and the relevant html code from index.html. Essentially I declare the images that make up the ul that goes into the scroller div, then clone and append them to simply extend the duration in the jquery code. @Imran Khan ive used both (window).on and (document).ready and neither operate as expected while node is running. both do work on local testing. I was under the impression that (window).on("load" will more explicitly wait for the DOM to load.

Comment: I think the issue is because of this line `app.use(express.json());` comment out this and try again.

Comment: @Imran Khan unfortunately commenting out that line didnt affect anything, neither locally or in node server

Answer (score 0):

Have you included
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>` in your `index.html` ?

Comment: yes, although i am using the full non minified version. I cant tell if the npm has differing versions or not, but both the linked script and jquery package are ^3.4.1. Ive also tried differing the order in which the js links are called in the html, with no results.